# Minimum permissions for a user to perform a mysqldump?

Tags: security, permissions, mysql

I want to start scheduling remote mysqldump crons, and I'd prefer to use a special account for that purposes. I want to grant that user the minimum permissions for getting a full dump, but I'm not sure the best way to go about that.

Is it as simple as

```
grant SELECT on *.* to '$username'@'backuphost' identified by 'password';
```

or am I missing a better way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe the user just needs select permissions on the tables to be backed up.

Edit: [This guy](http://www.drlock.com/blog/2006/12/22/mysqldump-permissions/) says to assign the "lock tables" permission too, which makes sense.

Comment: Is this still valid answer in 2017?

Comment: You don't need LOCK_TABLES permission if you aren't locking tables in the dump, for example if you use the `--single-transaction` flag. In fact, if you don't want the user to be able to lock tables by doing a dump, it's best to only give the SELECT permission.

Comment: For MySQL 8.0.21 and up, you also need `PROCESS` permission for the user, OR you need use the the `--no-tablespaces` option with `mysqldump`. See here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/273040/6235

Answer (score 11):

Also you need SHOW_VIEW, if there are views in your DB.

Answer (score 10):

For those wondering, here's the exact command:

```
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you need RELOAD too. So:

```
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, RELOAD ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 2):

And you need EVENT if you want to dump EVENTs too.

And you need TRIGGER if you want to dump TRIGGERs too. (despite what the manual says!)