# How to block the MySQL export option

Tags: mysql

I searched here and googled for this answer but had no success.

I need to block the export option from a user at my MySQL database, is there a way to do it? I already blocked the update and edit options.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Is this from some kind of write-only logging setup, or will users need to be able to read data?

Comment: Hello, users will be permited to read the data, but not allowed to dump the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Google did not reveal the MySQL documentation about that topic? My Google did: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privilege-system.html

The solution is the opposite of [Minimum permissions for a user to perform a mysqldump?](https://serverfault.com/questions/22712/minimum-permissions-for-a-user-to-perform-a-mysqldump)

Comment: I searched it, but did not found any instruction to deny dump...the other options I did!

Comment: Love "The solution is the opposite of Minimum permissions for a user to perform a mysqldump?"

Comment: Thanks, I´m portuguese and some words in english to search is difficult to me.